# Qt Cycle Crashes

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a method (SLOT) with Qt, and got crash, when I lunch this self-writen code.

I really can't find mistake. I hope it's somewhere in loops or maybe there is some secret sign.

```
QString data_elements[13];
    QString fileName = "C:\\Users\\cp1000\\Documents\\msl_register\\data.csv";
    QFile inputFile(fileName);
    if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream in(&inputFile);
        int elementId = 0;
        while (!in.atEnd())
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
                data_elements[i] = "";
            }
            QString line = in.readLine();
            for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
            {
                if(line[i] == ","){
                    elementId++;
                    i++;
                }
                if(line[i] == "\n"){
                    elementId = 0;
                }
                data_elements[elementId] = data_elements[elementId] + line[i];
            }
        }
        inputFile.close();
    }
```

It takes data from data.csv file, which look this.
[image: data.csv in Calc]

My task is:
Make method that gets and find row in data.csv, and than prints in GUI.

My data.csv file.

```
Reference,Batch,MSL,Open Date,Open Time,Close Date,Close Time,Drying start date,Drying start time,Spent,Left,Status
0028027,1231,1,07/12/2016,10:13,08/12/2016,15:41,13/12/2015,15:41,0,Neierobeюots,1
0028028,123123,1,07/12/2016,10:37,08/12/2016,15:45,13/12/2016,10:24,0,Neierobeюots,2
0028028,55554444,1,31/01/2017,15:26,08/12/2016,10:19,08/12/2016,15:41,0,Neierobeюots,2
XC0182,456,1,07/12/2016,09:27,08/12/2016,09:37,08/12/2016,15:41,0,Neierobeюots,3
VD0057-MSD,5999,5,15/12/2016,15:28,08/12/2016,13:33,13/12/2016,11:33,0,72,3
XC0182,555444555,1,07/12/2016,13:38,08/12/2016,13:38,08/12/2016,15:41,0,Neierobeюots,1
0028028,1232,2a,07/12/2016,10:14,08/12/2016,15:42,13/12/2016,15:42,1,Neierobeюots,2
0028029,123124,2a,07/12/2016,10:38,08/12/2016,15:46,13/12/2017,10:25,1,Neierobeюots,3
0028029,55554445,3,07/12/2016,10:20,08/12/2016,10:20,19/12/2016,12:52,1,Neierobeюots,3
XC0183,457,2,07/12/2016,09:28,08/12/2016,09:38,08/12/2017,15:42,1,Neierobeюots,4
VD0058-MSD,6000,4,07/12/2016,11:34,08/12/2016,13:34,13/12/2017,11:34,1,73,3
XC0183,555444556,2,07/12/2016,13:39,08/12/2016,13:39,08/12/2017,15:42,1,Neierobeюots,2
154-199-00-011,544325145,3,31/01/2017,13:58,31/01/2017,13:57,0,0,0,168,2
154-199-00-011,7777,3,31/01/2017,14:05,31/01/2017,14:05,0,0,0,168,1
```

Comment: Where do you get the Crash? What Crash? Did you run the code in a debugger?

Comment: You are showing an Excel Screen shot, not the csv file. I guess you have a line with more than 12 commas (maybe a comma inside a string?).

Comment: There's 12 elements in row and 11 comas in row.

Comment: Turn on warnings, set a higher warning level! `if(line[i] == ",")` is not correct, the right side is a string and not a char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You comes out of array bounds at:

```
data_elements[elementId] = data_elements[elementId] + line[i];
```

It happens because `line` doesn't contain `\n` at the end of the string and `elementId` is never reset to `0` at:

```
if(line[i] == "\n"){
  elementId = 0;    // <-- This code never reached
}
```

Documentation of the [`QTextStream::readLine`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#readLine) says:

> The returned line has no trailing end-of-line characters ("\n" or "\r\n")

Comment: And what I can use as delimiter?

Comment: @ЦунскийНикита You don't need any extra delimiter at the end of the string. All data is in `data_elements` when you reach the end of the line. Just put `int elementId = 0;` before `for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)` to fix the OutOfBound problem.